# Poisson distribution and properties of probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I need the step-by-step solution for this question.

If X and Y are aleatory independent variables with a Poisson distribution whose parameters are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively. Show that the aleatory variable $W=X+Y$ has a Poisson distribution too.

Comment: I was adding a long comment to your conditional expectation problem when it got deleted!

Comment: Sorry, I thought that maybe I had forgotten to put a detail.

Comment: I didn't notice that was another same question. I understand now how to do it.

Comment: @RebecaSilva I'm  pleased about that.